# Determining Improper Integral Convergence/Divergence

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does anybody know of any time efficient methods of determining whether a integral converges or diverges? The Comparison Test does give the answer for this problem, but I often find myself doing just as much arithmetic. Moreover, I would regardless like to investigate methods for determining convergence of integrals that are not natural, yet I cannot seem to find any literature online.

Comment: Integrating then taking the limit?

Comment: Almost always will the comparison test work, and if not, usually the alternating test suffices. However, depending on the integral, different approaches should be taken.